# Clustering using Random Forests Results

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, random-forest

I used a RF model to predict a rare event. After testing using multiple iterations, I settled on a model which provided decent results. I tested this model on a validation data I had kept aside before training the model. The result is similar here also. Now i extracted the votes(ie the probabilities)from the RF model for each training observation and also the probabilities from test & validation runs. Now I have a data frame of all my observation plus a column of the probabilities predicted by the random forest model. 
I want to preform clustering now on this data to understand the predictor values that are a part of my high probability conversion cluster. 
Any advice on what tools would be best to explore these clusters.

Comment: Why *cluster* at all? Why not simply create deciles or ventiles based on the predictions, rank the results from high to low average probability, then explore the highest ranking groups? It's much easier. Also, you might want to consider adding a column of residuals for analysis.

Comment: @DJohnson  thanks for the reply.. i wanted to do that but I also wanted to know the combinations.. for eg when Variable 1 has value <3 and Variable 2 is >200..etc they fall in a group of High Probability...

Comment: Sure. So, based on the grouping, average the variables within each group. Then index the group averages relative to the overall average for each variable creating a kind of IQ score or "t-test" proxy where around 100 is average or "normal" behavior for a variable, 120 and above is a "highly likely" characteristic and 80 and below is a "highly unlikely" characteristic. These are simple, directional heuristics that tell a story.

Comment: @DJohnson  Thanks, I have all categorical data 24 variables including 2 continuous variables which I binned to make them categorical. Do you have any suggestions that can help here..

Comment: What's your objective with this analysis? To identify a subset of variables that are most important or predictive of probability? To identify specific levels within variables that are most associated with predicted probability? Also, RFs may not be the best approach for analyzing and predicting sparse data. Have you explored any other methods?

Comment: Yes I have tried Logit & GBM but results don't vary by much. Any suggestions. Predictivity is important in terms of probability. Once I have the probability, then I want to understand the behavior of the predictors in High Probability or Low Probability group etc. I have managed to extract some of the rules from the random forest that give some direction regarding this.

Comment: That's my point. None of these methods give good results with sparse data. Gary King is a Harvard political scientist, methodologist who's written some good papers on modeling rare event data. His work is in int'l relations but is generalizable to any field. Here's a link ... http://gking.harvard.edu/category/research-interests/methods/rare-events His approach is worth a try. The "IQ Index" approach discussed in an earlier comment will still work with the results you've obtained.